# How do I save result of multiple “for” loops into a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, beautifulsoup

How can I add outputs of different for loops into one dataframe. For example I have scraped data from website and have list of Names,Email and phone number using loops. I want to add all outputs into a table in single dataframe.
I am able to do it for One single loop but not for multiple loops. 
Please look at the code and output in attached images.

By removing Zip from for loop its giving error. "Too many values to unpack"

1. Loop

```
phone = soup.find_all(class_ = "directory_item_phone directory_item_info_item")
for phn in phone:
    print(phn.text.strip())
##Output - List of Numbers
```

2. Code for df

```
df = list()
for name,mail,phn in zip(faculty_name,email,phone):
    df.append(name.text.strip())
    df.append(mail.text.strip())
    df.append(phn.text.strip())
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df
```

[For loops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoCLq.png)
[Code and Output for df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmsNZ.png)

Comment: Post code as part of the question as text. No links.

Comment: And please post the code as text and not as images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An efficient way to create a `pandas.DataFrame` is to first create a dict and then convert it into a DataFrame.

In your case you probably could do :

```
import pandas as pd

D = {'name': [], 'mail': [], 'phone': []}

for name, mail, phn in zip(faculty_name, email, phone):
    D['name'].append(name.text.strip())
    D['mail'].append(mail.text.strip())
    D['phone'].append(phn.text.strip())

df = pd.DataFrame(D)
```

Another way with a lambda function :

```
import pandas as pd

text_strip = lambda s : s.text.strip()

D = {
        'name': list(map(text_strip, faculty_name)),
        'mail': list(map(text_strip, email)),
        'phone': list(map(text_strip, phone))
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(D)
```

If lists don't all have the same length you may try this (but I am not sure that is very efficient) :

```
import pandas as pd

columns_names = ['name', 'mail', 'phone']
all_lists = [faculty_name, email, phone]

max_lenght = max(map(len, all_lists))  
D = {c_name: [None]*max_lenght for c_name in columns_names}

for c_name, l in zip(columns_names , all_lists):
    for ind, element in enumerate(l):
        D[c_name][ind] = element

df = pd.DataFrame(D)
```

Comment: The Dictionary method works but there is one problem when I checked the dataframe its showing only 4 rows and not the 6 as there are 6 entries in each of Name,Mail and Phone Number. While the 2nd method is giving me "error - arrays must all be same length". I am in learning stage so don't know about lambda function yet. Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: Sorry My bad. I just checked the HTML only 4 number are given. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is there a way around this? Is it possible to add null or zero values in place of missing values?

Comment: Are you sure that your lists have all the same length ?

For the second method lambda function may not be the most appropriate approach, see shaik moeed response with list comprehension which is surely better

Comment: No they are not of equal length, I checked.

Comment: I added a code that deals with this case. I am not sure that it's very optimized though

Comment: Hey Thanks. It worked. It just need some tweaks. I will try to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
data = {'name':[name.text.strip() for name in faculty_name],
        'mail':[mail.text.strip() for mail in email],
        'phn':[phn.text.strip() for phn in phone],}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Comment: Its giving me this error - AssertionError: 3 columns passed, passed data had 2 columns

Comment: add `index=False` in `pd.DataFrame()`. Please confirm it works or not?

Comment: I am getting this error - ValueError: arrays must all be same length. The length of list are different, I checked the HTML page, only 4 Phone no's are given.